# plot geom_lines() by different time periods

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(date_time = structure(c(1577836800, 1577840400, 
1577844000, 1577847600, 1577851200, 1577854800, 1577858400, 1577862000, 
1577865600, 1577869200, 1577872800, 1577876400, 1577880000, 1577883600, 
1577887200, 1577890800, 1577894400, 1577898000, 1577901600, 1577905200, 
1577908800, 1577912400, 1577916000, 1577919600, 1577923200, 1577926800, 
1577930400, 1577934000, 1577937600, 1577941200, 1577944800, 1577948400, 
1577952000, 1577955600, 1577959200, 1577962800, 1577966400, 1577970000, 
1577973600, 1577977200, 1577980800, 1577984400, 1577988000, 1577991600, 
1577995200, 1577998800, 1578002400, 1578006000, 1578009600, 1578013200, 
1578016800, 1578020400, 1578024000, 1578027600, 1578031200, 1578034800, 
1578038400, 1578042000, 1578045600, 1578049200, 1578052800, 1578056400, 
1578060000, 1578063600, 1578067200, 1578070800, 1578074400, 1578078000, 
1578081600, 1578085200, 1578088800, 1578092400, 1578096000, 1578099600, 
1578103200, 1578106800, 1578110400, 1578114000, 1578117600, 1578121200, 
1578124800, 1578128400, 1578132000, 1578135600, 1578139200, 1578142800, 
1578146400, 1578150000, 1578153600, 1578157200, 1578160800, 1578164400, 
1578168000, 1578171600, 1578175200, 1578178800, 1578182400, 1578186000, 
1578189600, 1578193200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), altura = c(80L, 67L, 69L, 86L, 110L, 137L, 161L, 
178L, 182L, 174L, 153L, 126L, 102L, 86L, 84L, 94L, 113L, 137L, 
161L, 180L, 189L, 183L, 164L, 136L, 107L, 86L, 77L, 81L, 95L, 
115L, 137L, 157L, 171L, 175L, 167L, 149L, 127L, 107L, 94L, 91L, 
99L, 114L, 134L, 156L, 173L, 181L, 177L, 160L, 136L, 112L, 94L, 
85L, 87L, 98L, 114L, 133L, 152L, 166L, 172L, 167L, 152L, 133L, 
113L, 99L, 93L, 97L, 109L, 128L, 150L, 168L, 178L, 175L, 161L, 
140L, 117L, 99L, 88L, 87L, 94L, 109L, 129L, 151L, 168L, 176L, 
173L, 159L, 138L, 116L, 98L, 88L, 89L, 102L, 123L, 147L, 168L, 
180L, 180L, 166L, 145L, 120L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I produce this graph:

[image]

I wanna to produce the same graph with the lines in different colors considering the mean of different time periods. For example, 6 hours, 12 hours, or a day.
In another way. Plot lines with the mean of different time periods (6h, 12h, 24h)

Thank's all

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(hour = lubridate::hour(date_time),
         date = as.Date(date_time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date_time, altura)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = . %>% 
              group_by(date, hour %/% 6) %>% 
              summarise_all(mean), aes(color = "6 hour")) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% 
              group_by(date, hour %/% 12) %>% 
              summarise_all(mean), aes(color = "12 hour")) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% 
              group_by(date) %>% 
              summarise_all(mean), aes(color = "day"))
```

[image]